# Argb value from rgb value

Tags: silverlight-3.0

I have rgb value 0, 69, 255. What would be it's argb value in silverlight. Is there any online converter that we can use.

Thanks in anticipation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ARGB or RGBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space) works just like RGB except you need an extra value for alpha or transparency. Now, 0 alpha means fully transparent, while 255 alpha is totally opaque. So you probably want use the same RBG values with 255 for the alpha. You may also want to check out the [documentation for Color.FromARGB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.fromargb%28v=vs.95%29.aspx#Y0).